# Gradient of a sum of logarithms

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, scalar-fields

Let the scalar field $f : {\Bbb R}_{>0}^n \to {\Bbb R}$ be defined by $$ f ({\bf x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln x_i $$ and find the gradient $\nabla f$.

---

I am new to matrix and vector derivatives. I am not sure if my understanding is right. Since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=\frac{1}{x_i}$, we have $\nabla f ({\bf x}) = \left( \frac{1}{x_1}, \frac{1}{x_2}, \dots, \frac{1}{x_n} \right)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Technically, the derivative of a vector is not defined (one has to be more specific about what kind of derivative is meant). What you have here is the gradient, which in some sense is a kind of vector derivative.

Comment: @Divide1918 Thanks, here what I want is the gradient and I modified the expression. Is my computing correct for the gradient?

Comment: Yes, the gradient that you have calculated is correct.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2726016/339790)